# Invoke function from another function in fishshell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, fish

I have created two function in .fish file

```
function mysqlstart
    cd ~/Projects/mysql
    docker-compose up -d
end

function projstart
    cd ~/Projects/projectName/
    php artisan serve
end
```

I want to invoke those two functions with a single function so that I don't have to type two alias on fish shell.

```
function startdev
    mysqlstart()
    projstart()
end
```

How to call functions from another function in .fish file?

I know I can run all four commands inside `stardev` function itself. But if I can call other functions, I can do other things as well and keep the .fish file DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are just like any other command:

```
function startdev
    mysqlstart
    projstart
end
```

Easy!

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Enjoying fish shell. If you are associated with fish shell, please add this functionality in the official docs.